# Browsers do not automatically display an inline file returned from a back-end java HTTP response

Tags: java, http, header, inline, content-disposition

I created a pdf on the fly with pdfbox, did corresponding tests and it is well formatted, I can save it, send it by email - and everything is working as expected.
Now that same pdf(without saving it), I returns it as a client hit a button; the respective request/response succeeds but the browser (any) do not display it.

Some context:

- angularJS 1.6 on the front-end
- jersey 1.9 as a rest api
- HTTP POST method
- No errors
- It just stays on the current page

**My code**

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream pdfStream = (ByteArrayOutputStream) generatePricePDF((Price) services.includeClient(price), null);

StreamingOutput streamingOutput = new StreamingOutput() {
    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        pdfStream.writeTo(outputStream);
        pdfStream.flush();
        pdfStream.close();
    }
};

return Response.ok(streamingOutput, MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf"))
        .header("Content-Length", pdfStream.toString().length())
        .header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=price").build();
}
```

As I mentioned it above, I can copy the encoded response:

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

and I can convert it (using an online converted), So there it is my pdf.

I have reviewed [Content-Disposition](http://test.greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/)
and it seems that the header are ok.

Answer (score 0):

I was not managing the response accordingly, this is the code added in the AngularJs 1.x Controller:

```
        $http.post('rest/processprice', $scope.price, {responseType: "blob"})
    .then(function(response) {
        var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: "application/pdf"});
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        $window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
    });
```

Managing the response this way, the pdf file opens up automatically.